# How to get the current category filter in the catalog collection..?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

```
<?php
$_category = $this->getCurrentCategory(); $_categoryCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
                 ->addCategoryFilter($_category)
                 ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                 ->addAttributeToSelect('is_brand','yes')
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('level','5')
                 ->addIsActiveFilter();
foreach($_categoryCollection as $cat){?>
<ui>
<?php //display current_Category image
     if($cat->getImageUrl()): ?>
      <img src="<?php echo $cat->getImageUrl(); ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
     <a href="<?php echo $cat->getUrl(); ?>">
<?php //display current_Category image
     echo $cat->getName(); ?>
     </a>
    </ul>
<?php   
        }
        ?>
```

I want to display categories which have the value "yes" for the category attribute "is_brand". and i want it to be fetched from the current category. I could not access getCurrentCategory() inside catalog/category_collection..

> > > i need only to fetch the category collection of level 5 only in the current category.
> > >       THE ABOVE CODE FETCHES COLLECTIONS WITH LEVEL 5 FROM ALL CATEGORIES.

Comment: Please explain your question!

Comment: Question Elaborated @ Rahul Kumar Das

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
$_category = $this->getCurrentCategory(); 
$path = $_category->getPath();
$_categoryCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
             ->addAttributeToFilter('path', array('like' => $path.'/%'))
             ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
             ->addAttributeToFilter('is_brand','1')
             ->addAttributeToFilter('level','5')
             ->addIsActiveFilter();
```

Comment: Fantabulous Marius... Perfect mage hack..

Comment: It's not a hack...is the way to do it. :)

Comment: :).........................

Answer (score 1):

Please remove  `->addCategoryFilter($_category)` which not `exclude  current category from Category collection`

This `addCategoryFilter($_category)`  only filter the product collection filter by category.

Use `addAttributeToFilter`() to filter the category  by `path` field.**Level 5 category 
must included current category path According to magento**

```
 $_categoryCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
                     ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                     ->addAttributeToSelect('is_brand','yes')
                     ->addAttributeToFilter('level','5')
                     ->addIsActiveFilter()
 ->addAttributeToFilter('path', array('like' => $_category->getPath().'/%'));
```

You can use `addIdFilter(categoryIds)`  if you want specific  ids categories

Comment: I do not want to manually add the entity ID Amit..Can you elaborate your answer please?

Comment: first clear , are you want the category collection of level 5 with exclude current category

Comment: i need only to fetch the category collection of level 5 only in the current category.

Comment: goto it... your question .. shorly give you solution

Comment: Can you send some predictions??

Comment: The above code fetches all of the category collection of level 5.

Comment: you are welcome :)